# How to enable php to read home directory from apache webroot script

Tags: php, apache

**This is what I am doing in my script, trying to read files and directory outside web root**

```
// on line number 17
echo file_get_contents("/home/admin_cs/Documents/ssh_logs/info_04102015.txt");   

// on line number 34
$file = scandir("/home/admin_cs/Documents/ssh_logs/");
```

**Errors I received**

> [Fri Sep 04 16:10:00 2015] [error] [client x.x.x.x] PHP Warning: 
>   file_get_contents(/home/admin_cs/Documents/ssh_logs/info_04102015.txt):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/virtual/Development/Admin/demo_jquery.php on line 17
>
> [Fri Sep 04 16:10:00 2015] [error] [client x.x.x.x] PHP Warning: 
>   scandir(/home/admin_cs/Documents/ssh_logs): failed to open dir:
>   Permission denied in
>   /var/www/html/virtual/Development/Admin/demo_jquery.php on line 34

**What I attempted**

```
[root@localhost admin_cs]# sestatus 
SELinux status:                 disabled

[root@localhost admin_cs]# chown -R apache.apache /home/admin_cs/Documents/ssh_logs/
[root@localhost admin_cs]# chown -R apache.apache /home/admin_cs/Documents/ssh_logs/*
[root@localhost admin_cs]# chmod o+x /home/admin_cs/Documents/ssh_logs/
[root@localhost admin_cs]# chmod o+x apache.apache /home/admin_cs/Documents/ssh_logs/*
```

Unfortunately nothing is working, someone help me to fix, I searched and read many posts on this forums, none of them solved my issue, anything else am I missing ? Please help me.

Comment: Have you checked the permission of file is it accessible

Comment: What's your os? Apache user depends on the os used. For ubuntu for example is www-data with group www-data and not apache!

Comment: you should also check that apache user has the r+x flag on each directory in the path, otherwise it will never have access

Comment: cenots 6.4 i am using

Answer (score 0):

Check how your host (or vhost) is configured in the apache conf files, there should be an option called `php_admin_value open_basedir` and a lot of routes to directories.
Add the routes to the directories you're trying to read.